# How should I report the author of a quote on English.SE?

Tags: discussion, answering-advice

When I include a quote from a book, blog, or a site, how should I report who is the author and from where the quote comes from?

- *Principia philosophiae*, René Descartes
- René Descartes, *Principia philosophiae*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say it doesn't really matter. You can do it in whatever way you find convenient. Clarity is always a virtue, of course, but I trust that won't be a problem for most people. If this question had been on the main site, I'd have said that `author, *title*` was most common in articles—at least in my field it is the standard (classics).